# dc.js rowChart topN without zeros

Tags: dc.js

I need to display the top20 alarms out of a large dataset.

The standard dc.js works great and using .rowsCap(20) in a rowChart gives me the top20.

I am now trying to remove the zero rows when the data is filtered below 20 entries.  Several similar posted questions pointed to the remove_empty_bins() from https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted which works correctly if I remove the .rowsCap(20) but fails I combine the two.

Using dc.js-2.0.0-beta.1 it fails on line 3415 for the group.top(_cap) call because the .top attribute is not available for the fake group generated by remove_empty_bins().

Same error when trying to add .top(20) when defining the fake group.

Is there an easy way to combine remove_empty_bins(original_group) with .top() or .rowCaps() for a rowChart ?

--Nico

Comment: A working example fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/hwhfxz2t/6/

Comment: A  fidle example with working removal of zero count rows: http://jsfiddle.net/hwhfxz2t/7/      It 'breaks' when you uncomment line 831  --Nico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a little bit more complicated to add `.top(n)` to the fake group:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    function non_zero_pred(d) {
        return d.value != 0;
    }
    return {
        all: function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(non_zero_pred);
        },
        top: function(n) {
            return source_group.top(Infinity)
                .filter(non_zero_pred)
                .slice(0, n);
        }
    };
}
```

The efficiency is not perfect, because this fetches all the groups in sorted order and then throws out all but the first `n`, while crossfilter is able to only pull the first `n` using a heap.  But this shouldn't matter unless the number of groups is huge.

Working fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/za8ksj45/3/

EDIT: note that the need to provide `group.top()` is being eliminated in dc.js 2.1.2, since the functionality overlaps with `chart.ordering()` and leads to confusing bugs. (As well as making these data preprocessors difficult to write.)

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Gordon.

Comment: this will show an "Others" bar - that is actually hidden, i.e. I can only see the label. Is there a way to completely hide it? Also, the "Others", as sums all the values, messes up the x-axis domain.

Comment: as answer to my previous comment: the "Others" will disappear with ".rowsCap(maxNRows).othersGrouper(false)".