# rowscap and filter applied in wrong order in DC.JS rowChart

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Still using DC.JS to get some analysis tools written for our tool performance.  Thanks so much for having this library available.

I am trying to show which recipe setup times are the worst for a given set of data.  Everything works great as long as you show the whole group.  When you only display the specified topN using .rowscap on the rowChart the following happens:

The chart will show the right number of bars and they are even sorted properly but the chart has picked the topN unfiltered bars first and then ordered them.  I want it to pick the topN from the ordered list, not the other way around.  See jsfiddle for demo.  (http://jsfiddle.net/za8ksj45/24/)

```
in the fiddle, the longest setup time belongs to recipeD.
But if you have more than two recipes selected before recipeD
it is dropped of the right (top2) chart.

line 099-110: reductio definition
line 120-140: removal of empty bins (works okay)
```

*(This is very similar to a problem Gordon helped resolved earlier ([dc.js rowChart topN without zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145149/dc-js-rowchart-topn-without-zeros)) and I reused the code from that solution.  Something went 'wrong' when I combined it with the reductio.js library.)*

I think I am not returning the value portion of the reductio group somewhere but have been unable to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that at the time you .slice(0,n) the group in your function to remove empty bins, the group is not ordered, so you effectively get a random 2 groups, not the top 2 groups. This is actually clear from the unfiltered view, as the "top2" view shows the 2nd and 3rd group from the "all" view, not the actual top 2 (at least for me).

The previous example worked because Crossfilter's standard groups are ordered by default, but in the case of a complex group like the one you are generating with Reductio, what should it order by? There's no way it can know, so Reductio doesn't mess with the ordering at all, which I suppose means it is ordering by the value property, which is an object.

You need to add one line to order your FactsByRecipe group by average and I think it should fix your problem:

```
FactsByRecipe.order(function(d) { return d.avg; });
```

Note that there can only be one ordering on a Crossfilter group, so if you want to show "top X" for more than one property of that group you'll need to create another wrapper (like the remove empty bins wrapper) but have the "top" function re-sort the group by the ordering you want.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Ethan,  Perfect.  Thank you so much for providing the explanation and answer.  Appreciate it.   I marked this as the correct answer.